# How to enable Hard Delete option in data loader?

Tags: data-loader

Can anyone have any insights regarding the activation of Hard Delete option in salesforce data loader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go into Settings and enable Use Bulk API. It should then appear as an option.

Comment: I have already assigned a permission set pertaining the 'Bulk API Hard Delete' permission enabled to sys admin but still I am not able to see the activated hard delete option in my data loader. Any guesses?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. You also need to go into the settings in the Data Loader application itself and enable that Use Bulk API option and save.

Comment: Great stuff, happy to help.